# How to organize graphics and drawing in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I've been working with Java graphics programming and I feel that I understands how it works.

One thing that I don't like/haven't grapsed yet is how to manage drawing lots of graphics (shapes, images, etc) on a panel.

All the books/tutorials I've currently being going through have you put all the drawing you want done in the paintCompnents/paint function. Ex,

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //do stuff here....
}
```

Thing is I have so much I want to draw that putting a bunch of code in one function is ugly, hard to read, and makes it hard to manage/edit...

I understands OOP but I'm new to graphics programming. How should I manage all the "data" I want drawn on my canvas (JPanel to exact). I'm currently calling functions inside the paint(..) method. Ex,

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    drawCars(g, x,y,wid,len,etc,etc);
}
```

then...

```
drawCars(Graphics g, int x, int y, int wid, etc etc){
    g.drawSomething(x,y,wid,len,)
    g.drawAnotherThing(x+90,y+60,etc, etc);
}
```

The problem is then in my JPanel class I have all these stray functions i have to manage.

And this is only for drawing "one page" of stuff.. I can't imagine having to switch views or a game screen where I could have a bunch of things animating on a page..

I'm just looking for direction on how to organize code drawn by the paint() method in java so I don't go crazy looking at my old work. Any tutorials, books (esp if they're free), or maybe **good** code to read would be very very appreciated.

Everything I've found thus far is about teaching what you "can" do with graphics/graphics2D/java but i'm looking for organization/style tips as suggested by experts..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make classes for logical things you draw like cars. Each object would know all it needs to know to paint it self like position, size and color. If you let all these objects implement a common interface you can all put them together in a list. When time comes to draw them you iterate over the list and call each objects draw method.

Apart from that document the drawing code well so that for each draw statement it is clear what part it is actual drawing.

Comment: Your saying make classes that implement a draw (paint()) method and iterate through them? In which case I  would have to take my Graphics/Graphics2D obj and pass it to these classes (so the paint method draw on the current panel)

Comment: You would pass the Graphics object to the draw/paint method.

Comment: Try and think of painting in layers.  Either create a series of methods that allow you replicate these layers in a logical manner or, as Eelke suggests, use classes to separate those layers.  This comes down to the complexities of your design

Comment: Thanks, that's what I will try to do hopefully. Do you have any recommended readings/material? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

spilt it up, in g call a method that would draw a certain part. 
if you were drawing a house rather then just drawRect, and stuff so

```
drawRoof(g);
drawDoor(g);
```

then in these you have the messy stuff like drawRect...

Is this helpful i might be misunderstanding what you are looking for...

Comment: That is what i'm currently doing. It's just for when I have a bunch of things it becomes a lot functions, and when i want to do collision detection I don't have objects to get data quickly from but rather i have to go through my functions and identify what space they're taking up... etc etc...

Comment: gotcha, i think @Eelke has the idea then you can have more info stored and easily accessed. So is you question answered or are you looking for more still?

Comment: I think I got it. I didn't realize that a different class (a non jpanel class) could be used to create shapes and draw them. Then finally have this class instantiated in the paint method of my current jpanel class.

Comment: Yea, and you can even add in properties like `doesContain(x,y)` to see if a point is contained within the image, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @Zeb, you wouldn't happen to know of any good code/books/tuts on the topic would you?